# Does this sum help to show the irrationality of $\gamma$ constant?

Tags: sequences-and-series, soft-question

Does this sum is anywhere near to help, to show that the $\gamma$ the Euler's constant is near to an irrational number?

$$\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\left(H_n-2H_{2n-1}-\frac{1}{4n}\cdot\frac{4n-3}{2n-1}+\ln(4n-2)+\gamma\right)=0$$

where $H_n$ [harmonic number](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Harmonic_number)

Comment: Whether $\gamma$ is rational is unknown, but it's real, and all real numbers are arbitrarily close to both rationals and irrationals.

Comment: Whence the sum?